# Multiple negative lookbehind with 2-3 words between and commas

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

consider that I want to get the phrases that contain party and have been great!.

Therefore, the cases I am missing are those with commas or points that mark a separation between sentences (1) or a maximum of 2 or 3 words between the no|bad and the party (2).

This is my current regex.

```
(?<!\b(no|bad)\b.*)party

is there any party?  --> ok
no party --> ok
it was a bad and poor party --> ok
oh, this was a bad party --> ok
no man, this was great party --> BAD (1) (consider the comma or a point that means end sentence)
no sir it was indeed a barbaric party --> BAD (2) (consider a maximum of two or tree words between no|bad and party)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```cs
(?<!\b(?:no|bad)\b(?:[^,\w]+\w+){0,2}[^,\w]+)\bparty\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cb%28%3f%3ano%7cbad%29%5cb%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2c%5cw%5cn%5d%2b%5cw%2b%29%7b0%2c2%7d%5b%5e%2c%5cw%5cn%5d%2b%29%5cbparty%5cb&i=is+there+any+party%3f%0d%0ano+party%0d%0ait+was+a+bad+and+poor+party%0d%0aoh%2c+this+was+a+bad+party%0d%0a%0d%0ano+man%2c+this+was+great+party%0d%0ano+sir+it+was+indeed+a+barbaric+party).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\b(?:no|bad)\b(?:[^,\w]+\w+){0,2}[^,\w]*)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is

  - `\b(?:no|bad)\b` - a whole word `no` or `bad`
  - `(?:[^,\w]+\w+){0,2}` -  zero, one or two occurrences of any 1+ chars other than a comma or word chars and then one or more word chars
  - `[^,\w]+` - and then one or more chars other than `,` and word chars.
- `\bparty\b` - a whole word `party`.